# Django primary key prefix and length

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am looking to add a custom primary key to my models. Here is what i have so far.

```
ticket_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

I basically want the primary key for each record to look like this, auto-incrementing from 001.

```
AB001
AB002
AB003
AB004
```

How would I accomplish this?

Many Thanks

Comment: So you each time want to add `AB`, or is that some part of the key to generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the save method, get the last id entry in the database, extract the numeric part of the id-string and increment it by one:

```py
def save(*args, **kwargs):
    if self.ticket_id is None:
        last_ticket_id = self.__class__.objects.all().order_by('ticket_id').last()
        if last_ticket_id is None:
             last_ticket_id = '000'
        last_ticket_id_number = ''.join(substr for substr in last_ticket_id if substr.isdigit())
        leading_zeros = len(last_ticket_id_number) - 1
        incremented_number = int(last_ticket_id_number) + 1
        incremented_number = str(incremented_number).zfill(leading_zeros)
        self.ticket_id = f'AB{incremented_number}'
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this worked exactly how I wanted it too. I just had to add SELF to the parameters. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set an autoincrement field like:

```
user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

After this, you can run this command on the database side. You can run this python command by using signals:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE user_id RESTART WITH 10000;
```